# custom hash function for pair of enum values used as unordered_map key

Tags: c++, hash, enums, unordered-map

I'm trying to use a `std::pair` of enum values as key for an unordered_map container, but I have difficulties in defining a custom hash function.

I tried the following:

```
// Enum and pair declaration
enum ShapeType{ PLANE, BOX, SPHERE };
typedef std::pair<ShapeType, ShapeType> ShapePair;

// unordered_map declaration
typedef void(*CollisionMethod)(const Shape*, const Shape*, CollisionData*);
typedef std::unordered_map<ShapePair, CollisionMethod, ShapePairHash> CollisionMethodsTable;
```

I don't understand how define correctly `ShapePairHash` functor. I tried the following:

```
struct ShapePairHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(const ShapePair &pair)
    {
        return std::hash<std::size_t>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<std::size_t>()(pair.second);
    }
};
```

but I get error C3840 (`expression having type 'type' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'function'`)on VS compiler.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to declare a custom hash function to be used with `unordered_map`?

Comment: Aren't you just missing a trailing  const on your function definition to specify that the functor is unchanged by calling the function?

Comment: Yes, it seems that was just the missing const specifier to cause the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a last enum value, and then use it to generate the hash (actually a perfect hash). Note that this assume that the number of possible enum values is low enough so that (suppose that the number of enum values is N): `N * N + N < MAX_UINT`

```
enum class ShapeType : unsigned int { PLANE = 0, BOX = 1, SPHERE = 2, LAST = 3 };

struct ShapePairHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(const ShapePair &pair) const
    {
      return static_cast<std::size_t>(pair.first)
           * static_cast<std::size_t>(ShapeType::LAST)
           + static_cast<std::size_t>(pair.second)
    }
};
```

Also, for your compilation problem you just need to declare the function *const*.

Answer (score 3):

Your operator() method should be const:

```
std::size_t operator()(const ShapePair &pair) const
```